# Angular 5 file-saver saveAs CSV file encoding to ANSI

Tags: angular, csv, encoding, filesaver.js

I use Angular 5 + `"file-saver": "^1.3.3"` + `"@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0"`

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
const filename = parts[1].split('=')[1];
const blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', response.body], { type: 'text/csv' });
saveAs(blob, filename);
```

create **UTF-8** file

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
const filename = parts[1].split('=')[1];
const blob = new Blob([response.body], { type: 'text/csv' });
saveAs(blob, filename);
```

create **UTF-8 w/o BOM** file

But I need create **ANSI** file (for Excel and an other client)

I try `{ type: 'text/csv;charset=ansi;' }` but do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not possible change UTF-8 to ANSI in Front-End part(Angular). I change

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/csv")
```

by

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/csv;charset=ISO-8859-1")
```

in my Back-End (Springboot)